# Mailgun forwarding e-mail as POST data to Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, mailgun

I can't figure this one out, it's not in the request.JSON and the request.data is coming up as empty bytes in the debug. There appears to be a post but the data is disappearing? Is this a bug with Flask?

Here's a link to their documentation page that has a Django example: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html#supported-actions-for-routes

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out: Clue was in the header

`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Flask automatically strips out **form data** into **request.form** leaving request.data and request.json empty:

```
@app.route("/test-mail/", methods=["POST"], strict_slashes=False)
def test_mail():
    print(request.form)
    return 'OK'
```